# What role does .pipe(take(1)) have here?

Tags: angular, rxjs

What role does pipe(take(1)) have when calling the method from authService?

```
this.authService
  .signIn(email, password)
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`take(1)` will unsubscribe after 1 value has been received. This is useful for tidying up subscriptions to long running observables when you know you only want the first result.

Comment: Thanks! And the pipe() method has to always be used when subscribing correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. `pipe` is used when you want to preform some *operation* on the observable.

Comment: @LucasTony `pipe` is here to combine your Observable with operators (like `take`). But you can simply subscribe without it.

Comment: @LucasTony To add what Pac0 says, `pipe` also turns out to be useful when you want to add some common operation to an observable that will be subscribed at a higher level. So if your service makes an http request that is transformed once it is received, you would do something like `return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(/*mapping logic*/));` to share the mapping logic with all subscribers.

Comment: @NicholasK I suspect the authservice uses a httpClient. And since Http reuquests will give you an Observable with only one result and then complete. take(1) is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From the [rxjs-docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take):

> Take returns an Observable that emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable. If the source emits fewer than count values then all of its values are emitted. After that, it completes, regardless if the source completes.